# Lock Down Users on Cygwin SFTP Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, ssh, security, cygwin-sshd

How do I lock down sftp users in Cygwin so that they can't read from random directories such as /etc.  i set up local windows accounts for each sftp user on the machine.  I've used /etc/fstab file to move each user's home directory to c:/FTP.  I've locked those down so the users can only access their own folder. I denied "list folder contents" on the Cygwin directories.  The users can not see the directory structure when they sftp into the server.  But the users can still download a file from the cygwin directories if they know the path.

Comment: Can you show the permissions on the Cygwin directories on your server? It sounds like the users you've created are not completely locked down.

Comment: The cygwin directories has everyone with read access.  The problem is that those directories and sub directories and files are not setup to inherit permissions from parent directory.  I think I would have to remove the access to "everyone" to every single file and folder maybe?

Comment: You could turn off bypass traverse checking. If it's not needed on that server.